# QCompleter and QLineEdit for multiple words

Tags: java, c++, qt

Is there any way to have the QCompleter to act like an autocomplete for multiple words?

Someone has any idea how to do it?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with Java?

Comment: Qt is also available for java so in a way it could be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if I understand correctly:

```
QStringList wordList;
wordList << "alpha and beta" << "omega" << "omicron" << "zeta";

QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter(wordList, this);
completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);

QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
lineEdit->setCompleter(completer);
```

If you type alp then you get the completion "alpha and beta" which is more than one word. There is no limit.

Update after clarifications:

Seems that what is requested is starting a new autocompletion after a delimiter value. In the current case this delimiter will be a space. An equivalent example would be the
[tree model completer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tools-treemodelcompleter-example.html) from the Qt examples. This example illustrates how to solve the same situation.